# Custom CTA button plugin CK5Editor

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I started creating my own CK5 Editor plugins, and am now stuck at the plugin for creating a custom call-to-action button.

**What I want**

I've created a button in the editor toolbar to create a new button. What I want to happen is that a button element is created, and the user is able to edit it's textual content.

`<button> [this must be editable text] </button>`

**Where I got stuck**

So I made it so far that a button element is created as soon as I click on the action in the toolbar. But as soon as I start typing, the button disappears and a paragraph is created. It looks like the cursor is inside the button element though. I've been reading through the API documentation for a while now, but I didn't get any further.

**My code so far**

First I register the callToAction schema

```
const schema = this.editor.model.schema

schema.register('callToAction', {
    isObject: true,
    allowWhere: '$block',
    inline: true
})
```

Then I define the converters

```
conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
    model: 'callToAction',
    view: {
        name: 'button',
        classes: 'cta-button'
    }
})

conversion.for('dataDowncast').elementToElement({
    model: 'callToAction',
    view: {
        name: 'button',
        classes: 'cta-button'
    }
})

conversion.for('editingDowncast').elementToElement({
    model: 'callToAction',
    view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
        /* The Button element is editable on selection */
        const button = viewWriter.createContainerElement('button', {
            class: 'cta-button',
        })

        /* Makes the element editable */
        return toWidgetEditable(button, viewWriter)

    }
})
```

I Also created a command to execute the creation of the button element

```
function createCallToAction(writer) {

    const callToAction = writer.createElement('callToAction')

    return callToAction

}
```

**The actual question**

How can I create the button with a standard placeholder text, let's say ***Enter text***, and let the user edit this text inside the button? I've searched the internet for answers, looked at other plugins, but didn't get the solution I need.

Hope someone can help me, or at least send me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, `toWidgetEditable(button, viewWriter)` does not change the 'editability' of an element, it just creates the widget. So when you create a container-element with:

```
const button = viewWriter.createContainerElement('button', {
    class: 'cta-button',
})
```

This cannot later on 'become' editable.

Instead, create an editable element with:

```
const button = viewWriter.createEditableElement('button', {
        class: 'cta-button',
    })
```